# netbeans project doesn't run when jre 7 installed

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I have a rather large NetBeans 7.0.1 project, which is released as an installer. When a second PC has this program installed, and has Java 6 installed, it runs fine, however if this PC happens to have Java 7 installed, some parts of the program fail.

Why is this and how can I solve this?

One part where it fails: there is a bean class that, when right-clicked in the GUI, shows a pop-up menu with 'Properties'. When clicked, it opens a property sheet, however, fields which are not primitive types show "(No Property Editor)". I can't trace this back because most of the logic happens within native NetBeans API code and a lot of Reflection is used.

Edit: I also installed NetBeans 7.4 with Java 7 on the development machine, changed all modules to 1.7 source, recompiled, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of differences between Java 6 and 7 so pointing to the specific problem is difficult. Probably the API's you are using are based on Java 6. You have two options make your project Java 7 compatible or install Java 6 on the machines that use your project/application. The latter would be the easiest in my opinion.